# Python program that takes the name of the file and opens it, creating a new file with the data taged?

Tags: python, xml, file, input, output

For example a file such as:

```
def player():

Player    
9    
Mike    
M    
180    
90    
6    
2    
3.81    
.283
```

Would return data such as:

```
<player>
<number> 9 </number>
<playername> Mike </playername>
<gender> M </gender>
<height> 175 </height>
<weight> 95 </weight>
<wins> 6 </wins>
<losses> 2 </losses>
<era> 3.81 </era>
<batting> .283 </batting>
</player>
```

If you could give me any info on files to data, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking here...

Comment: Is there a question here? Or a writing code request? What do you have so far? Note that people on SO are volunteers and appreciate well constructed questions which show effort - **not** *write this for me* ones - if you have specific problems, please let us know

Comment: do you know that def is used for a function. and that indentation is to be used while defining a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is to read each line, split the line by spaces. After that, I will print the element from array with specific tag. You can store tag in a list and the ending tag could be the pair converted to list, and insert '/' on 1 position.

Comment: I made an example for you [link](http://pastebin.com/M3BXrqnA)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data of the file using readlines(). Apart from that your question is really unprecise.